# Insert Bool from Access Query into SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, insert, boolean

I am not sure how to insert boolean values from an Access query into a SQL Server table.

Access generally uses 0 for false, -1 for true. In SQL Server it's 1 for true.

So my question is this: if I want to insert a true value into my SQL Server table, can I just say -1 anyway, and SQL Server will know how to interpret it? Or do I **have** to put the 1 for true ?

EDIT: additionally, is it possible to just put true instead of a numeric value into the insert statement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quick sample to illustrate:

```
CREATE TABLE BoolTest(SomeText VARCHAR(50), SomeBool BIT)

INSERT INTO dbo.BoolTest (SomeText, SomeBool)
VALUES ('Text 1', 0), (`Text 2', 1), ('Text 3', -1)

SELECT *
FROM dbo.BoolTest
```

I get this result:

[image]

So SQL Server interprets *anything other* than `0` as a `True` value.

Comment: Thank you for the help and quick example !